# Angular 4: using the methods of feature module in it's components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm now thinking about creating feature module for User and this module has components like:

1. authorization;
2. registration;
3. profile;
4. restore-password.

I want to create methods like:

1. createUser();
2. deleteUser();
3. updateUserProfile().

   in UserModule and then use it in the components listed above.

how can I use methods of UserModule in registrationComponent and ect. ?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich: how can I use methods of UserModule in registrationComponent and ect.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-your-first-angular-2-components

Comment: Create a common ts file and inherit it in others Components

Comment: @Sreemat: Yes I already did so, but I want methods in Module

Comment: Can you describe Module?

Comment: @Sreemat: Well? UserModule is all about creating user, autheticating user, deleting and updating

Comment: U mean UserModule is a NgModule?

Comment: @Sreemat: Yes feature module...

Comment: Then you create the common ts as service and inject into all the componenets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use some methods in more than one component you build a so called service. It is a typescript class with the `@Injectable()` decorator:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  createUser(user) {
    // reach out to backend via http
  }

  // some other functions that have to be shared and used by components
}
```

This service can be injected like this:

```
import { UserService } from 'services/user.service.ts'

@Component({
  selector: 'user-create'
})
export class CreateUserComponent {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  createUser(user) {
    this.userService.createUser(user); // now you can call your method from the service like this
  }
}
```

Comment: how about handling form data like: user name, login, password, email, phone number and etc...

Comment: There is a great documentation for angular: https://angular.io/guide/forms